# UK pulp magazine with a cover featuring a warrior, a pile of worms, and a damsel in distress

Tags: story-identification

In the mid-eighties, some guy I knew had a kind of pulp magazine (fantasy) which was from the UK, I guess. The cover was some acryl painting with a warrior wielding a sword while standing on a pile of worms. I guess the mandatory damsel-in-distress (half-naked with a bikini-like armor or similar) was also present.

I'm not sure whether the content was a novel, a comic, or both. Any ideas on what this magazine was?

Answer (score 8):

Sounds like any number of covers from the comic *2000AD*. Maybe Sláine – he fought the worm god, Crom.

Or possibly Conan from [*The Savage Sword of Conan*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Savage_Sword_of_Conan) (1974-1995).

[image: Black and white Conan slaying a creature]

Comment: The question said it was an acrylic painting though.

Comment: And here's a complete gallery of 2000AD covers: http://www.2000ad.org/?zone=covers&page=coversindex ...doesn't seem like they started doing totally painted covers until the 600's in 1989, so I doubt this could be the magazine.

Answer (score 3):

One of the [*Tunnels and Trolls*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunnels_%26_Trolls) adventure books sort of fits: [*Gamesmen of Kasar and Mistywood*](https://gamebooks.org/Item/2725/Show) (1986).

[image: Gamesmen of Kasar and Mistywood cover]

The art's by Josh Kirby, apparently.